# as.data.frame() returns a list instead of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, import, linear-regression, coercion

I imported a .csv dataset into R, and want to convert it to a data frame. The strucure of the data is simple, rows are participants and columns are variables. The problem is that R is unable to coerce the data into a data frame.

`d1 <- as.data.frame(read.csv("data.csv"))`

`typeof(d1)`

Returns
`[1] "list"`

Any ideas why this might be the case?
If it's impossible to coerce d1 into a data frame, are there any implications for statistical analyses(e.g., does linear regression work differently with data frames vs. lists)?

Comment: The output of `read.csv` is a data frame. I wonder why you used `as.data.frame` for a data structure which is already a data frame.

Comment: No need for `as.data.frame`, read.csv returns a data.frame. And dataframe is a list, too. Try `is.list(mtcars)` and `is.data.frame(mtcars)`

Comment: used as.data.frame because the read.csv would return a list. However, I wasn't aware that dataframes are actually lists. The is.data.frame(d1) returns TRUE. Thank you both.